# How to use SqlBulkCopy with SMO and transactions

Tags: c#, sql, smo

I'm trying to create a table using SMO, and further use the SqlBulkCopy object to inject a bunch of data into that table. I can do this without using a transaction like this:-

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(connectionString)));
var database = server.Databases["MyDatabase"];

using (SqlConnection connection = server.ConnectionContext.SqlConnectionObject)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Table table = new Table(database, "MyNewTable");
        // --- Create the table and its columns --- //

        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "MyNewTable";
        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Basically I want to perform the above using a SqlTransaction object and committing it when the operation has been completed (Or rolling it back if it fails). 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Things -

A - [The SQLBulkCopy method is already transaction based by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  That means the copy itself is encapsulated in a transaction and works for fails as a unit.

B - [The ServerConnection object has methods for StartTransaction, CommitTransaction, RollbackTransaction.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.aspx)

You should be able to use those methods in your code above, but I suspect if there is an issue with the table creation your `try/catch` will handle that appropriately.